# Using ng-repeat how to show default selected value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Using ng-repeat how to show default selected value using angularjs

my code :
I have currencies :

```
"currencies":["AWG","BAM","BBD","BDT","BGN","BHD"]

selected currency is "BBD"
```

In my HTML

```
<select ng-init='toCurrencyCode = currency.toCurrencyCode' ng-model= 'toCurrencyCode' ng-options="toCurrencyCode as code for code in currencies">

</select>
```

If I wrote like this means last value as selected by default. I need exact selected currency.
Please update your idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/lSu1M58gMtqlOCsaCCrG?p=preview

```
 <select ng-init='toCurrencyCode = currency.toCurrencyCode' ng-model= 'toCurrencyCode' 
 ng-options="code for code in currencies">
```

Comment: Hi this is fine. But if we are using with in ng-repeat means that selected value is not showing. Can u help me for this.

Comment: @Sangeetha.V do you want to use ng-repeat inside select ?

Comment: No. select is used inside of ng-repeat. Already am displaying one row using ng-repeat. With in that row i need this select. please help me for this.

Comment: @Sangeetha.V more likely that happens ng-repeat is creating separate scope for each row. It is difficult to help you without code can you please update my plunker and I will help you

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/lSu1M58gMtqlOCsaCCrG?p=preview
I updated my problem here.. please check..

Comment: @Sangeetha.V You send me link to my plunkr. You need to click fork on your Plunker will create new solution with new link.

Comment: sorry.. This is the updated link
http://plnkr.co/edit/lSu1M58gMtqlOCsaCCrG?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58764/discussion-between-sylwester-and-sangeetha-v).

Comment: @Sangeetha.V that is still this same link